# How to get all the elements an unknown length python list?

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

And I have a string which contains `{}` markers for the format method:

```
>>> my_string = 'First element = "{}" and the Second element = "{}"'
```

I want to interpolate the first elements from `my_list` into `my_string` like this:

```
>>> print my_string.format(my_list[0], my_list[1])
First element = "a" and the Second element = "b"
```

However, When I write the code:

1. I don't know how many `{}`s there will be in `my_string`
2. I don't know how many elements there will be in `my_list`
3. I do know that the number of elements in #2 will be greater than or equal to #1.

What python expression can I use to do the interpolation given facts number 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Do you need my_string to always list off every element?

Comment: No.... I don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the splat operator: ("unpacking argument lists" officially)

```
print(my_string.format(*my_list))
```

It converts each element into another positional argument.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that `format` ignores excess values? I just tried finding it and failed.

Comment: Didn't see it in documentation, but: `"{} {}".format(1,2,3) == '1 2'`. It could be an unofficial implementation detail...

Comment: Yeah, I had successfully tested it as well, in both CPython 2 and CPython 3,  but I feel uneasy about it if I don't see it documented.